# Semantics of execution occurrence in sequence diagrams

Tags: semantics, modeling, uml, sequence-diagram

I am teaching a course that uses UML as the tool to model systems. In the course we teach sequence diagrams and while preparing the course I found that there is no clear definition of the semantics of an "execution occurrence". 
For example. If an object makes a self call "wait for input" and this call is inside an execution occurrence, can the object receive messages? Obviously I think yes, because it is waiting for messages.

But this counters the idea that execution occurrences mean that the object is currently "busy" or "active".

Any help/ideas? My conclusion was to leave the subject and tell the students to disregard execution occurrences. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, note that Sequence Diagrams **don't have precise semantics** (and AFAIK, they're not included in the new [base UML semantics](http://www.omg.org/spec/FUML/)) so therefore they're more or less "open to interpretation", to suit your specific sketching needs.

In general, what does a Sequence Diagram mean? Is it a universal specification ("this is how the system will always behave" therefore there are no other allowable behaviors)? Or is it an existential specification ("this is a scenario which the system should support" therefore a system that doesn't is incorrect)? Or is it merely a description ("this might happen"). There is no answer, because SDs don't have precise semantics like that.

(Granted, [some formalizations do exist](http://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=formalization+of+semantics+of+sequence+diagrams&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart), but then it depends what you want to teach.)

Therefore, I don't think that this quesiton has a unique answer:

> "If an object makes a self call "wait for input" and this call is inside an execution occurrence, can the object receive messages?"

That said:

According to [this tutorial](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_sequencediagram.html), execution occurence (EO) denotes:

> the execution occurrence, or activation of a focus of control

Look also at the next diargam, about self-messaging, where you have nested execution occurences.

Moreover, [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#execution-occurrence) it is simply said that EOs are:

> moments in time at which actions or behaviors start or finish

Finally, EOs reference [execution specifications](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#execution) which represent:

> a period in the participant's lifetime when it is (a) executing a unit of behavior or action within the lifeline, (b) sending a signal to another participant or (c) waiting for a reply message from another participant.

I hope it helps :)